# Find Class Within ID Group

Tags: jquery

I'm beginning work on a ratings system and have found a gaping hole in my jquery knowledge.  My code so far is:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#rate").delegate("div","click", function() {
        var targetid = $(this).attr("id");
        var voteval = $( '#' + targetid + ' span').html(); 
        if(isNaN(voteval)) { var voteval = 0; }
        voteval++;
        $( '#' + targetid + ' span').text(voteval);
    });

});
</script>
```

Which successfully locates the ID of a div within the #rate group and manipulates the data within the associated span.

My problem is I want to be able to locate the div within the group that contains a certain class.  In plain english, when the user clicks it will look for ".active" and remove it, if it exists, then insert .active on the 'current' target (this).

Comment: `voteval` can't be `NaN`

Comment: btw - use `on` instead of `delegate`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in your click event:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

If a class active exist, it will remove it.

If you have multiple `#rate`, then you need to find the closest (and it should be class instead of id) like that :

```
var $parent = $(this).closest('#rate');
$parent.find('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove active class from others and add to current `div` like this

```
$("#rate div").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#rate").on("click", "div", function () {
        //    get text of span and make it int, also init to 0 if it's not a number
        var thisTextToInt = parseInt($(this).children("span").text()) || -1;    
        //    increment the text and set it to the span
        $(this).children("span").text(thisTextToInt+1);    

        $('#rate .active').removeClass('active');    //    remove previous active
        $(this).addClass('active');                  //    make this active
    }); 

});
```

Although, I must say this is not a good way to set the text to your elements. Better keep the data somewhere else, and bind them to the view elements so they update automatically.